# Overloaded operators in Complex class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I implement complex class with overloaded operators. It gave me some errors after I compiled, I don't get how I solve them.The errors are generally about that "complex.cpp" does not recognize the Complex type, even there is no error on "complex.h".

complex.h

```
    /*Definition of Complex Class. This class contains overloading operators.*/

    #ifndef COMPLEX_H
    #define COMPLEX_H

    using std::ostream;
    using std::istream;

    class Complex{

        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Complex &);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream&, Complex &);

    public: 
        Complex(double = 0.0, double = 0.0);//constructor
        Complex operator+(const Complex &) const;//addition
        Complex operator-(const Complex &) const;//subtraction
        Complex operator*(const Complex &) const;//multiplication
        const Complex &operator=(const Complex &);//assignment
        bool const &operator==(const Complex &) const;//equivalent
        bool const &operator!=(const Complex &) const;//not equivalent
    private:
        double real;//real part
        double imaginary;//imaginary part
    }; 

    #endif
```

complex.cpp:

```
 //Definition of Member Functions of the Complex Class

    #include <iostream>

    using std::cout;
    using std::ostream;
    using std::istream;

    #include "complex.h"

    //Constructor
    Complex::Complex(double r, double i)
    :real(r), imaginary(i){};

    //Overloaded addition operator
    Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex &operand2) const
    {
        return Complex(real + operand2.real, imaginary +operand2.imaginary);

    };
    //Overloaded subtraction operator
    Complex Complex::operator-(const Complex &operand2) const
    {
        return Complex(real - operand2.real, imaginary - operand2.imaginary);

    };
    //Overloaded assignment operator
    const Complex& Complex::operator=(const Complex &right) 
    {
        real = right.real;
        imaginary = right.imaginary;
        return *this;
    };
    //Overloaded multiplication operator
    Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex &operand2) const{

        return((real *operand2.real)-(real*operand2.imaginary), (real*operand2.imaginary)-(imaginary*operand2.real));
    }

    bool Complex& Complex::operator==(const Complex &right) const{

        if ((real == right.real) && (imaginary == right.imaginary))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
    bool Complex& Complex::operator!=(const Complex &right) const{

        if ((real != right.real) && (imaginary != right.imaginary))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
    ostream &operator<<(ostream&output, const Complex &complex){//Print as Complex object as (a,b) with overloaded version

        output << '(' << complex.real << "," << complex.imaginary << ')';//it allows usage as cout<<a<<b<<c
        return output;

    };
    istream &operator>>(istream&input, Complex &complex){//Get input from the user.

        input.ignore();//ignore '('
        input >> complex.real;
        input.ignore();//ignore ","
        input >> complex.imaginary;
        input.ignore();//ignore ')'
        return input;//it allows usage as cin>>a>>b>>c
    }
```

Error Lists:

1- syntax error : identifier 'Complex'          62      1

2- error C2065:'complex' : undeclared identifier    58  1

3- error C2065: 'complex' : undeclared identifier   65  1

4- error C2065: 'complex' : undeclared identifier   67  1

5- error C2086: 'bool Complex' : redefinition   48  1

6- error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'   56  1

7- error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'      40   1 
8- error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'   48  1

9- error C2228: left of '.imaginary' must have class/struct/union   58  1

10- error C2228: left of '.imaginary' must have class/struct/union  67  1

11- error C2228: left of '.real' must have class/struct/union       58  1

12- error C2228: left of '.real' must have class/struct/union   65  1

13- error C2373: 'Complex::operator !=' :redefinition; different type modifiers 48   1

14- error C2373: 'Complex::operator ==' : redefinition; different type modifiers 40  1

15- error C2556: 'int &Complex::operator !=(const Complex &) const' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'const bool &Complex::operator !=(const Complex &) const' 48 1

16- error C2556: 'int &Complex::operator ==(const Complex &) const' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'const bool &Complex::operator ==(const Complex &) const'        40  1

17- error C2805: binary 'operator >>' has too few parameters 62 1

18- error C4430: missing type specifier -int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 40  1

19-error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    48  1

20-error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int        56  1

Comment: Please post the exact compiler errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Istream and Ostream operators need to be declared as friend public members in the Complex class in order for them to access private members of the Complex class.

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&output, const Complex &complex){//Print as Complex object as (a,b) with overloaded version

    output << '(' << complex.real << "," << complex.imaginary << ')';//it allows usage as cout<<a<<b<<c
    return output;

};
friend istream &operator>>(istream&input, Complex &complex){//Get input from the user.

    input.ignore();//ignore '('
    input >> complex.real;
    input.ignore();//ignore ","
    input >> complex.imaginary;
    input.ignore();//ignore ')'
    return input;//it allows usage as cin>>a>>b>>c
}
```

On the other hand, you are declaring two types at the same time. The comparisons shall return bool so I remove Complex&:

```
bool Complex::operator==(const Complex &right) const{

    if ((real == right.real) && (imaginary == right.imaginary))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

I see a bug in operator !=, replaced && by || as different complex numbers can have same real or imaginary parts.

```
bool Complex::operator!=(const Complex &right) const{

    if ((real != right.real) || (imaginary != right.imaginary))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

That's all I see, try and tell us...

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing complex& has solved all errors suddenly, and also thanks for the bug warning.

Answer (score 3):

you can see below all code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using namespace std;

class Complex
{
    private:
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Complex&);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream&, Complex&);
        double real;
        double imaginary;
    public:
        Complex(double = 0.0, double = 0.0);
        Complex operator+(const Complex&) const;
        Complex operator-(const Complex&) const;
        Complex operator*(const Complex&) const;
        const Complex &operator=(const Complex &);
        const bool operator==(const Complex&) const;
        const bool  operator!=(const Complex&) const;
};

Complex::Complex(double r, double i)
{
    this->real = r;
    this->imaginary = i;
}

Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& operando2) const
{
    return Complex(real + operando2.real,imaginary + operando2.imaginary);
}

Complex Complex::operator-(const Complex& operando2) const
{
    return Complex(real - operando2.real,imaginary - operando2.imaginary);
}

const Complex& Complex::operator=(const Complex &right)
{
    real = right.real;
    imaginary = right.imaginary;
    return *this;
}

Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex &operando2) const
{
    return ((real * operando2.real) - (real * operando2.imaginary), (real * operando2.imaginary) - (imaginary*operando2.real));
}

const bool  Complex::operator==(const Complex &right) const
{
    if((real == right.real) && (imaginary == right.imaginary))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

const bool Complex::operator!=(const Complex &right) const
{
    if((real != right.real) || (imaginary != right.imaginary))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream&output, const Complex &complex) 
{
    output << '(' << complex.real << "," << complex.imaginary << ')';
    return output;
}

istream &operator>>(istream&input, Complex &complex)
{
    input.ignore();
    input >> complex.real;
    input.ignore();
    input >> complex.imaginary;
    input.ignore();
    return input;
}

main(void)
{
    Complex c1(4,5);
    Complex c2(8,9);
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
    Complex c4 = c2 - c3;
    Complex c5 = c1 * c3;
    Complex c6(4,5);
    bool varBool = c6 == c1;
    varBool = c6 != c2;

    c1 = c2 = c3;

    cout << c3 << endl;

    cin >> c3;
    cout << c3 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning I didn't like is resolved with...

```
Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex &operando2) const
{
    return **Complex**((real * operando2.real) - (real * operando2.imaginary), (real * operando2.imaginary) - (imaginary*operando2.real));
}
```